# mqtt.publish() blocked thread

Tags: python, flask, mqtt, uwsgi

I am writing a website in `Flask`, using it with `uwsgi + nginx`. For publish message to topic use `Flask-MQTT`.

`webapp/__init__.py`

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
import grpc.experimental.gevent
grpc.experimental.gevent.init_gevent()

from flask import Flask
from .tasks_spooler import run_thread_publish
from flask_mqtt import Mqtt

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MQTT_BROKER_URL'] = 'temper.chost.com.ua'
app.config['MQTT_BROKER_PORT'] = 1883
app.config['MQTT_CLIENT_ID'] = 'flask_mqtt'
app.config['MQTT_CLEAN_SESSION'] = True
app.config['MQTT_USERNAME'] = 'testee'
app.config['MQTT_PASSWORD'] = 'tester'
app.config['MQTT_KEEPALIVE'] = 10
app.config['MQTT_TLS_ENABLED'] = False
app.config['MQTT_LAST_WILL_TOPIC'] = 'home/lastwill'
app.config['MQTT_LAST_WILL_MESSAGE'] = 'bye'
app.config['MQTT_LAST_WILL_QOS'] = 0
app.config['MQTT_LOGGING'] = False

mqtt = Mqtt(app)

mqtt._connect()

type_topic = ["/Control", "/Data"]
m_request_state = {"comm": "3"}
qos_request = 2
qos_sub = 0
POOL_TIME = 2

@mqtt.on_connect()    
def _handle_mqtt_connect():
    mqtt.subscribe("1111111" + type_topic[1], qos_sub)
    run_thread_publish.spool("1111111", "1111111" + type_topic[0],
                             m_request_state, qos_request, 
                             POOL_TIME)
```

`webapp/tasks_spooler.py:`

```
from uwsgidecorators import thread, spool
from webapp import app, mail, mqtt
import json
import threading
from gevent import sleep

@thread
def thread_publish(name_thread, topic_req_res, msg, qos_req, poll_time):
    threading.current_thread().name = name_thread
    print(name_thread)
    try:
        while True:
            mqtt.publish(topic_req_res, msg, qos_req)  <---- Here bloked
            sleep(poll_time)
    except Exception as ex:
        print("Error publish: " + str(ex))


@spool(pass_arguments=True)
def run_thread_publish(dev_id, topic_req_res, m_req_state, qos_req, poll_time):
    create = False
    try:
        for thr in threading.enumerate():
            if thr.name != dev_id:
                create = True
            else:
                create = False
                break
        if create is True:
            msg = json.dumps(m_req_state)
            thread_publish(dev_id, topic_req_res, msg, qos_req, poll_time)
    except Exception as ex:
        print("Error add publish thread: " + str(ex))
```

`project.ini:`

```
[uwsgi]
env = PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
module = wsgi:app

disable-logging = true
enable-threads = true
gevent = 1024
gevent-monkey-patch = true
buffer-size=32768

socket = /home/sammy/projectnew/projectnew.sock
socket-timeout = 30
chmod-socket = 664
thunder-lock = true
spooler = /home/sammy/projectnew/webapp/mytasks
import = webapp/tasks_spooler.py
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
```

`wsgi.py:`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from webapp import app, socketio

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, use_reloader=False)
```

Comment: Where are you setting up the MQTT client and starting the MQTT network loop?

Comment: I changed my question. I connect forcibly use `mqtt._connect()`